# Does text-transform: Capitalize work for <option> elements, and if so in which browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<select>` element within which I would like to Capitalize the text displayed in each `<option>` tag.

For  instance, I would like the 2 values here to be *Bar* and *Baz* (not *bar* and *baz*)

```
<style>
    option { text-transform: Capitalize; }
</style>

<select name="foo">
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
    <option value="baz">baz</option>
</select>
```

This does not appear to work in my Chrome (14.0.835.202) but does work in my Firefox (8.0) and IE 8.

**Edit: Added `<style>` tag for clarity**

Comment: The title of your question mentions "text-transform: Capitalize", but the text of the question doesn't show how you're using it. Just `select option { text-transform: capitalize; }`?

Comment: Apparently this was an ongoing bug for Chrome and has been corrected in 16 + 17, but I can't verify as I'm still on 15: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31349

Comment: Works if you style 'select' now in Chrome.

Comment: This has since stopped working in FF, works in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/dtavqsh6/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this currently [a bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31349). The code below is the proper way to do what you're asking:

```
select option {text-transform:capitalize}
```

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/cATEt/) (view in something other than Chrome)

**Additional Information:**

I think you'll also find that the above method does not work in Safari as well. If you want a cross-browser solution, JavaScript will be your only option.

If you're open to it, here's a simple jQuery example:

```
$("option").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.text().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $this.text().slice(1));
});
```

And [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/nTuZz/).

> ** UPDATE **

This question was originally answered in 2011. The above-referenced bug has since been squashed, and the CSS below is enough to capitalize each option in **all browsers.**

```
select, select option {text-transform:capitalize}
```

Comment: Works if you style 'select' now in Chrome.

Comment: works best if you do on both actually: `select, select option {text-transform:capitalize}`

Comment: select option {text-transform:capitalize} not working for firefox

Comment: As of 2022 I'm not seeing this working in Chrome to style just the `option`. You can style the `select` but my form uses a font that looks on brand for the form elements to have caps, but the `select option` I want to be `capitalize`, yet it has no effect. Looking in the inspector shows the rule and it's not being overridden, just not supported, even with `!important`.

Comment: As of 2023, this does not appear to work in Firefox

Comment: @Scribblemacher I just tested in firefox and it works properly. Are you testing the JS from 2011 or the CSS?

Answer (score 24):

This will work in all browsers:

```
select {text-transform:capitalize}
```

Comment: This one is better, simple and straight forward.

Comment: How could you just capitalize the first word crossbrowser if there are more than one in each option?

Comment: @Marcel I answered this on another thread look for my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242592/angular-js-how-to-autocapitalize-an-input-field/22561169#22561169

Comment: When on iphone chrome), only the selected option seems to be capitalised, others in scrollable menu stille are lowercase.

Comment: This works for the displayed/choosen value only, but when you click on the list , the other elements are not capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small jQuery script to get it working in Chrome too:

http://jsfiddle.net/p6wbf/1/

Comment: Works if you style 'select' now in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

select option {text-transform:capitalize}

Use Above CSS make sure your option values are not in UPPERCASES. if they are, first lower them using strtolower() in PHP and the style will work for you perfectly.