# Can Angular Filter Input

Tags: input, filter, angularjs

Is there a way to filter through inputs in Angular? I'd Imagine

```
var input = e.$filter(/a-zA-Z/);
```

Comment: If you need two way filtering, then you need a directive. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15346236/1218080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but you can force a pattern on an input with the ngPattern directive.

```
<form name="theForm" novalidate>
   <input type="text" ng-model="foo" ng-pattern="/a-zA-Z/" required/>
   <button ng-click="update()" ng-disabled="theForm.$invalid">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know ng-pattern does that, but ng-pattern doesn't filter, it only validates. is there a filter that can say ng-filter ="/a-zA-Z/" and only take input of alphabets