# Is it possible to have AngularJS internationalize numeric inputs?

Tags: html, angularjs, localization, cross-browser

We're trying to have AngularJS internationalize `<input type='number' />` values.

We've included the localization file (e.g. `angular-locale_it-it.js`), but the values are still displayed using the English locale.

This is a problem because our back-end (and management) expects numeric values to be in the user's locale, and receiving `123.45` instead of `123,45` causes an error.

You can find an example [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sb8V/).

It works in Chrome 27

[image: Screenshot of the result in Chrome]

but it's not working in Firefox 21 and Internet Explorer 10.

[image: Screenshot of the result in Firefox]

Comment: I'm running into the same issue for Germany currency formatting on inputs.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer you want, but maybe it helps you a little bit:

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/iyulaj/1/

Using a directive you can take the data of the input, parse it and then put it to the `$scope` variable. Please see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController (`$parsers` and `$formatters`. I took it from: [Using angularjs filter in input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343068/using-angularjs-filter-in-input-element)).

The directive could search for a comma and replace it with a dot. It could look like this:

```
angular.module('MyModule').directive('numberinput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
                //convert data from view format to model format
                return data.replace(',', "."); //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                //convert data from model format to view format
                return data.replace('.', ","); //converted
            });

            // http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController

        }
    };
});
```

The input field:

```
<input ng-model='value' type='text' numberinput='' />
```

Also note that the input is now a text field. Have a look at this: http://jsbin.com/iyurol/1/

The input is a number field. But type `11,5` and it will output `ùndefined` (note that I live in Germany and we're using the comma-notation). So the browser doesn't 'parse' the number correctly if it's not in dot-notation, even if you live in regions with comma-notation...

Please correct me, if there's something wrong about that ;)

Answer (score 2):

It could be not related to angular. IMHO that should be provided by the browser. It should be driven by the `lang` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
...
```

See more details at [HTML5 number inputs – Comma and period as decimal marks](https://www.slightfuture.com/webdev/html5-input-number-localization.html)

Comment: Unfortunately (as we would expect) this doesn't work with IE11.

Answer (score 0):

As type of the data to be formatted usually is a number shouldn't we convert the number to a string before calling replace()? 
I got an error when model data has a numeric value.
The following works better:

```
      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          //convert data from model format to view format
          return (''+data).replace('.', ","); //converted
      });
```