# Filter input with directive

Tags: angularjs

html

```
<input type="text" name="usernr" ng-model="userNr" placeholder="user nr"
                               tabindex="2" ng-usernumber/>
```

javascript

```
app.directive('ngUserNumber', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
                    console.log("inside directive");
                    ctrl.$parsers.push(function(data) {
                        console.log("//convert data from view format to model format");

                        data = data.toString() + " test";

                        return data; //converted
                    });

                    ctrl.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                        console.log("//convert data from model format to view format");

                        data = data.toString() + " test";

                        return data; //converted
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

I would like to replace the data provided by ng-model, with data from inside the directive. But nothing happens. How come the custom directive isn't used?

I followed this doc: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html 
other source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346236/489856

Comment: Is the link function being called\executed?

Comment: No (the logs aren't executed)

Comment: Your directive name in html should be `mg-user-number`

Comment: Typo? `ng-usernumber` will be normalized as `ngUsernumber` instead of `ngUserNumber`.

Comment: @rogerz jep that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it just like that :

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){

  });

app.directive('ngUsernumber', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

                    var format = function(data){
                        console.log("//convert data from view format to model format");

                        if(data !== undefined){
                          data = data.toString() + " test";
                        }


                        return data; //converted
                    };

                    ctrl.$parsers.push(format)
                    ctrl.$formatters.push(format);

                }
            };
        });
```

Working plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/iA85KC?p=preview

You have to respect CamelCase for your directive note : ngUsernumber -> ng-usernumber if you do ngUserNumber -> ng-user-number

Hope it helps !

Comment: Your plnkr, looks ok. But "test" doesn't get appended?

Comment: I've update the plunlkr if you look under the input the good string is print

Comment: ng-model = double binding. So how come only the paragraph shows "yourtypedstring test" and the inputfield doesn't add test to ng-Model?

Answer (score 0):

In order to reflect changes to the current input you need to call

```
ctrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
ctrl.$render();
```

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14425022/1606662)

Quote from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue):

> In any case, the value passed to the method should always reflect the current value of the control. For example, if you are calling `$setViewValue` for an input element, you should pass the input DOM value. Otherwise, the control and the scope model become out of sync. It's also important to note that `$setViewValue` does not call `$render` or change the control's DOM value in any way. If we want to change the control's DOM value programmatically, we should update the `ngModel` scope expression. Its new value will be picked up by the model controller, which will run it through the `$formatters`, `$render` it to update the DOM, and finally call `$validate` on it.