# How do I use a date filter in ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems like it should be simple but it has eluded me. I would like to convert my date string to a date object and filter how it is displayed.

I have a simple angular app and controller

```
myApp.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.MyDate = Date("2014-09-23T15:26:49.1513672Z");
})
```

I have JSON returned from the server and the date I am working with is a string in the above format

from the angular documentation about [date filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
  <span>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
```

this works and the out put is:
Oct 28, 2010 8:40:23 PM

When I try to use the filter on $scope.MyDate as follows:

```
  {{MyDate | date:'medium'}}
```

the date is not formatted but looks like this:
Wed Sep 24 2014 07:40:02 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Ultimately I would like to bind an input text box to this value and filter it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="MyDatee | date:'medium'"/>
```

I am hoping once i get the simple version working I can get my actual problem solved with the text input.

Here is a [plunker with the above code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ActFrWBaK0LR6AK10qtR)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the first part, use `new Date()` instead:

```
$scope.MyDate = new Date("2014-09-23T15:26:49.1513672Z");
```

Second, you can create a directive to format the model in the `input` (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343068/using-angularjs-filter-in-input-element))

The markup is like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="MyDate" formatted-date format="medium" />
```

And the directive is like:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('formattedDate', function(dateFilter) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      format: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from view format to model format
        return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
      });

      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from model format to view format
        return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
      });
    }
  }
});
```

See updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLNknnfsPjcNePX3pHsA?p=preview)

Comment: This is great. Can there be an extension to validate the data as well?

Answer (score 4):

in your $scope.MyDate please replace it with

```
$scope.MyDate = new Date("2014-09-23T15:26:49.1513672Z");
```

Answer (score 2):

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Se6Cv6ozF0B7F0X6gjl?p=preview

but you can't use filter inside input to formate date inside input please see here

[Using angularjs filter in input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343068/using-angularjs-filter-in-input-element)

```
 $scope.MyDate = new Date("2014-09-23T15:26:49.1513672Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the date format like this

`<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{MyDatee | date:'medium'}}"/>`