# Display the custom string ("Today") on set date (date=today), in the Angular-UI-Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am implementing the [Angular-UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) as a directive, and I am trying to get it to display today's date as the string 'Today' rather than 2015/04/27.

Is this possible? I could easily change `$scope.dt` to `"Today"` but then if I want to save that to my database, I'll need to convert it back, which is messy. It looks like a custom format....but I can't see from the code here how that would be done?

Comment: im not familiar with the angular datepicker, but can you set the val and text seperately?

Comment: @LiamHT the text is set from the textual representation of the `ng-model`. I don't think there is a separate text and val to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a filter that would wrap original `date` filter provided by AngularJS and accept custom format, forwarding formatting to `date` if format is default or passed date is not today.
Here is a sketch:

```
.filter('my_date', ['dateFilter', function (dateFilter) {
    function filter(date, format, timezone) {
        var today  = new Date();
        if (!(date instanceof Date)) {
            date = new Date(date);
        }

        if (format == "today") {
            if (date.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear() && date.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && date.getDate() == date.getDate()) {
                return "Today";
            } else {
                format = "yyyy/mm/dd"; // this is default
            }
        }

        return dateFilter(date, format, timezone);
    }
    return filter;
}])
```

To use:

```
{{dt | my_date:'today'}}
```

There is a room for improvements here: you can check out more dedicated procedure for converting to date whatever was passed into filter in AngularJS source (it accepts JSON in particular); default format can be parameterized.

*NOTE*. The outlined technique will work if you are ready to render input with date by yourself - i.e when you can select which filter to use. It will not work for ready-to-use `datepicker-popup` from AngularUI - it uses built-in `date` filter and there seems no way to override that except modifying sources of AngularUI. If popup is what you need you'll have to add "popup logic" by yourself

Comment: I could always replace the `input` with a span fed from the `ng-model`, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly like in the example on the page you linked to in your question.

Comment: Looks like it is possible with some hackery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18887843/1075247