# Overwrite angular.js var NUMBER_REGEXP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

I needed angular to validate numbers in scientific notation format within number input fields.

In order to do this I replaced the following constant within angular.js file (line: 18652 v0.13):

```
var NUMBER_REGEXP = /^\s*(\-|\+)?(\d+|(\d*(\.\d*)))([eE]+[-]?\d+)?\s*$/;
//var NUMBER_REGEXP = /^\s*(\-|\+)?(\d+|(\d*(\.\d*)))\s*$/;
```

Now values like 0.045e-10 are are accepted as numbers within inputs of the type "number".

I wish to do this from my app instead of from the angular.js file in order to not have to remember to change this again on update of the framework files.

I tried to simply overwrite in the first line of my main app controller like:

```
NUMBER_REGEXP = /^\s*(\-|\+)?(\d+|(\d*(\.\d*)))([eE]+[-]?\d+)?\s*$/;
```

But didn't work.

How can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15346236/2025923 might help

Answer (score 0):

Create a your own validation on the inputs that you want to accept this format.
You could create your own constant containing the regex.

```
module.constant('SCIENTIFIC_NOTATION_NUM_REGEX', /^\s*(\-|\+)?(\d+|(\d*(\.\d*)))([eE]+[-]?\d+)?\s*$/);
```

Then inject it on any controller or directive that you want to use it and use it on the template.

```
<input name="scientificNotationNum" ng-pattern="ctrl.SCIENTIFIC_NOTATION_NUM_REGEX">
```

This example reflect the case when you bind the constant to the controller instance using controllerAs on the view.
Other possibility is to bind it to the $scope.
Or you could [create your own custom input validation](http://angularjs.io/how-to-create-a-custom-input-validator-with-angularjs/) to reuse all over your app.