# AngularJS - Bind input to value with filter and update it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have an input bound to an object property and with a filter applied to it.

```
<input value="{{object.field | filter}}">
```

The problem is that if I programmatically change *object.field*, the value displayed inside the input **doesn't change**, however in the DOM Inspector I see the correct (new) value. I verified to digest/apply the changes to the scope and the object.field variable does change correctly, the issue seems to be only in the input displayed value.

I cannot provide an example since there's too much code involved.

Does anyone know where I should look for errors??

Comment: brief code that will make sure to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think I solved it. The input had a wrong event attached to it that was preventing the value to correctly update. The "value" attribute was changing but the $(input).val() wasn't.
Consider the problem solved, thank you.

Comment: glad that you solved.

Answer (score 0):

No need to set value in that way. ng-model takes care of it.
Valid syntax is:

```
<input ng-model="object.field">
```

For filtering you can look at this answer:
[Using angularjs filter in input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343068/using-angularjs-filter-in-input-element)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but unfortunately ng-model can't be used with filters.

Comment: Ye, you right. But you can use $parsers in your controller to filter value. Look at "Using angularjs filter in input element" link in my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ng-model to bind your data into input box instead {{expression}}

Comment: ng-model doesn't support filters, does it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't support filter, just bind the data.

Comment: To bind it I have to use value="{{xx}}"...Anyway I solved it, an event was preventing the edits, read the question comments for a more detailed info. Thank you anyways :)