# Is it possible to add a directive to the input of a md-autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I use a directive which formats my input. Now I also want to use it with the input of a md-autcomplete.

I think that I have read using two directive with isolated scope on one element isn't possible. Am I right? 
Otherwise how can I get access to the input of a md-autocomplete?

Thank you in advance

further information: (angular material 1.1 + angular 1.5.*)

source of component:

```
.component('payeeInformation', {
       bindings: {...
  },                
  templateUrl: 'payeeInformationTemplate',

  controller:function(autocompleteService, $rootScope, $scope, $element, $compile, $document){
    var ctrl = this;
    this.genericAutocompleteSearch = autocompleteService.genericSearch;

    addDirectiveToInputOfAutomplete('#my-input');

    function addDirectiveToInputOfAutomplete(id){
      var myAutoCompleteInput = angular.element($element[0].querySelector(id));
      myAutoCompleteInput.attr("my-directive");
      $compile(myAutoCompleteInput)($scope);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use services or pass in variables into an isolated scope to share data.  This might be relevant for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343068/using-angularjs-filter-in-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof of concept seems to work - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rrBjjm?editors=1010)

Markup

```
<md-autocomplete ... md-input-id="myAutoCompleteInput">
```

JS - directive

```
.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            text: '@text'
        },
        link:function(scope,element){
            console.log(scope.text);
        }
    };
});
```

JS - controller

```
$timeout(function () {
  var myAutoCompleteInput = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#myAutoCompleteInput'));
  myAutoCompleteInput.attr("test", "test");
  myAutoCompleteInput.attr("text", "blah");
  $compile(myAutoCompleteInput)($scope);
});
```

In the console you can see that the `console.log` in the directive outputs "blah". The $timeout in the controller is required to get the `md-autocomplete` element with the id.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case $element[0].querySelector('#my-input') is null. Could that be the case because i work in a component? Furthermore I use the "controller as"-syntax should I $compile the input with $scope or on this? Now both doesn't work

Comment: @ThomasZoé First thing, when you inspect the element in the browser does the input actually have the id "my-input"?

Comment: @ThomasZoé It being in a component shouldn't be a problem... Could you add the component (or a simplified version of it) to your question?

Comment: @ThomasZoé I think if you wrap the code in addDirectiveToInputOfAutomplete in a $timeout it should work. Here's a test  - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zKOkyO?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you now the directive is added to the input. Additional I changed myAutoCompleteInput.attr("my-directive"); to myAutoCompleteInput.attr("my-directive", "");

Comment: @ThomasZoé Glad to be of help. I learned quite a bit answering your question. :-)

Comment: Now I have a aftereffect. The md-input-container of the autcomplete doesn't have the class 'md-input-invalid'. I would be grateful if you have a look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243892/md-input-container-of-md-autocomplete-doesnt-get-expected-classes