# md-input-container of md-autocomplete doesn't get expected classes

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I use angular 1.5.7 and angular material 1.1 and have the following problem. 
At first I dynamically added a directive to the input of an autocomplete.

```
$timeout(function () {
 var myAutoCompleteInput = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#myAutoCompleteInput'));
 myAutoCompleteInput.attr("myDirective", "");
 $compile(myAutoCompleteInput)($scope);
});
```

This directive validates and formats the input. 
The directive works fine but the md-input-container hasn't the class md-input-invalid. If I use the directive with a normal input the class was set. 
Without the class the input looks like a valid one.

How can I sovle my problem?
Would a watch on the classes of the input work? & How?

Thanks in advance

jsfiddle with input and autocomplete: 
https://jsfiddle.net/p4knm9or/3/

I changed the function above to

```
 $timeout(function () {
    var myAutoCompleteInput = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#add-ng-iban'));
    myAutoCompleteInput.attr("ng-iban","");
    $compile(myAutoCompleteInput)($scope);

    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return myAutoCompleteInput.attr('class');
    }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      var mdInputContainer = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('#add-ng-iban').parentElement);
      if(newValue.indexOf('ng-invalid') !== -1 && newValue.indexOf('ng-touched') !== -1 && mdInputContainer.attr('class').indexOf('md-input-invalid') === -1){
        mdInputContainer.attr("class", mdInputContainer.attr('class') + " md-input-invalid");
      }else if(newValue.indexOf('ng-invalid') === -1 && mdInputContainer.attr('class').indexOf('md-input-invalid') !== -1){
        mdInputContainer.attr("class", mdInputContainer.attr('class').replace('md-input-invalid', ''));
      }
    })
  });
```

It works, but it isn't performing fast. I think It is also against the concept of angular.

Comment: Show the directive `myDirective` code.

Comment: myDirective is ng-iban from https://github.com/mmjmanders/ng-iban

Comment: Maybe `ng-iban` don't set `$valid` on form.

Comment: the submit button is disabled if the form is invalid. If everthing  is entered only the iban isn't right the form is invalid. 
Everthing seems working fine, only the style of the md-input-container is wrong

Comment: With the `angular-material` I had an issue. When the `ngModelController` passed from a wrong state to another error state, the `style` were not updated. For example, from the `ng-required` to `n-pattern`. Can you create jsfiddle, that reproduce issue?

Comment: Here you go, https://jsfiddle.net/p4knm9or/3/
Just rembering you should enter a valid iban(i.e. AT84 3400 0000 0006 2679) into the input or the autcomplete. If it is invalid the input is red the autocomplete isn't

Comment: I changed my function, now it works, but I think it is a very ugly solution because the concept of angular is against it. 

May you consider it?