# Use Exclamation Point as First Character with AngularJS Filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm filtering a list of objects in AngularJS using ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="application in page.applications | filter: {DisplayName:page.ApplicationSearchValue}">
    {{application.DisplayName}}
</tr>
```

If the user puts an exclamation point as the first character in the search box, then Angular interprets that as a negation symbol. So `!MyApplication` returns all the applications except for MyAppliction.

I tried using a custom function as description in [the Angular documentation for filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), but the exclamation point never finds its way into the function.

I found that the code is going through the following function in the [AngularJS source code](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js), which is basically enforcing that the exclamation point gets special treatment:

```
function deepCompare(actual, expected, comparator, matchAgainstAnyProp, dontMatchWholeObject) {
  var actualType = getTypeForFilter(actual);
  var expectedType = getTypeForFilter(expected);

  if ((expectedType === 'string') && (expected.charAt(0) === '!')) {
    return !deepCompare(actual, expected.substring(1), comparator, matchAgainstAnyProp);

      .....
```

My current "solution" is to change the filter object to:

```
filter: {DisplayName:(page.ApplicationSearchValue.indexOf('!') == 0 ? page.ApplicationSearchValue.substring(1) : page.ApplicationSearchValue)}
```

But it's only a matter of time until QA figures out that the problem would still occur if someone started the search box with `!!`.

Is there a common pattern for dealing with this situation?

Comment: Show us how you tried using a custom function.

Comment: `ctrl.filterFunc = function(actual, expected) {
    expected = expected.indexOf('!') == 0 ? expected.substring(1) : expected;
    return actual.toLowerCase().indexOf(expected) != -1; 
}`
But the value of expected never included the exclamation point.

Comment: Don't pass a comparator. Pass a function as the unique argument of the filter. Make this function return true if the element should be accepted by the filter, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a directive I modified from this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346236/2908576

```
MyApp.directive("noNegation", [function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
                while (data.indexOf("!") == 0)
                    data = data.substring(1);
                return data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

It ignores all exclamation points at the beginning of the input. That means that a search for `!!!MyApplication` still returns MyApplication, even though the exclamation points aren't in the name.