# text-transform: capitalize; Also affects Placeholder

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder, capitalize

I have the following simple input.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="What is your username?" />
```

When I use `text-transform: capitalize;` to capitalize the first letter of each word, the placeholder also gets capitalized: `What Is Your Username?`

How can I keep the placeholder intact?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could style the placeholder--

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-transform: initial;
}

:-moz-placeholder { 
   text-transform: initial;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  
   text-transform: initial;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { 
   text-transform: initial;
}
```

Comment: While `initial` value [is not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility), you could use `lowercase` value instead.

Comment: @HashemQolami yes, it was just an example of how to style the placeholders separately from the inputs :)