# How to convert text to uppercase while typing in input field using angular js

Tags: angularjs-directive

I know that is posible with jquery but I dont know how to do that with angular js, please any sugestion?

```
       function mayuscula(campo){
            $(campo).keyup(function() {
                           $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
            });
       }
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs force uppercase in textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388562/angularjs-force-uppercase-in-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in HTML template or via JS using the angular `uppercase` filter.

```
<div>
  <label>Input 1</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="first">{{ first | uppercase }}
</div>
```

If you need to change the value in-place, use `toUpperCase` when ever value is changed.

```
<div>
  <label>Input 1</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="first" ng-change="text = text.toUpperCase()">
</div>
```

---

Above in preferred approaches. Here's yet another way to achieve same result using `$watch` but this is not recommended. See comments section.

```
<div>
  <label>Input 2</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="second">
</div> 

var unwatch = $scope.$watch('second', function(val) {
    $scope.second = $filter('uppercase')(val);
}, true);

$scope.$on('$destroy', unwatch);
```

Related Plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/susiRn

Comment: I haz anonymous downvote w/o comment, on accepted (and only) answer. That's always nice!

Comment: (Extensive) usage of watchers 1) has a negative impact to performance in angular 2) make logical flow more complex. Therefore a directive is a better way to solve this,

Comment: True dat. I update my answer as not recommended approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create a directive for this!

Check the code:

```
directive('uppercase', function() {
return {
    restrict: "A"
    require: "?ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        //This part of the code manipulates the model
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(input) {
            return input ? input.toUpperCase() : "";
        });

        //This part of the code manipulates the viewvalue of the element
        element.css("text-transform","uppercase");
    }
};
})
```

For its usage, here's an example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" uppercase />
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but sadly does not integrate well with the directive: `ng-pattern`