# most angular way to capitalize input on blur

Tags: angularjs

what is the most angular way to capitalize an input on blur?

my view code:

```
<input name="initials" type="text" ng-model="vm.initials" minlength="2" maxlength="4" ng-blur="vm.capitalizeInitials()"
```

my controller code:

```
vm.capitalizeInitials = function(){
      vm.initials = angular.uppercase(vm.initials);
    }
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at this link, it may help you: [Angular force uppercase in textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388562/angularjs-force-uppercase-in-textbox)

Comment: As per miquelarranz's link, you could write a directive that capitalizes the input on entry. Alternatively, you could use CSS to capitalize the input field, then simply run ``.uppercase`` when the data is saved. The prior is the more "angular" way, though the later is certainly easier.

Comment: I'm thinking of doing the 'easiest' way: <input name="initials" type="text" ng-model="vm.initials" minlength="2" maxlength="4" ng-blur="vm.initials = vm.initials.toUpperCase()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both of them, if you are looking for the easiest and fastest way use the solution that you're saying.

```
<input name="initials" type="text" ng-model="vm.initials" minlength="2" maxlength="4" ng-blur="vm.initials = vm.initials.toUpperCase()">
```