# Modify the textbox value during keydown AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following scenario as

my input text box will be having a text value assume it to be "**sampletext**" in lower case.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="txtValue" />
```

so when the user types **s** textbox value should be **S**

Again the user will type **a** 
so now text will be **Sa** and it should change as **SA**

simple words what he types it should turn into upper case before the next character he types.

I tried something like this in two different textbox as the below code

```
 Before
      <input type="text" ng-model="numberValue"/>

 After 
      <input type="text" ng-model="numberVal"/>
```

script controller as

```
$scope.$watch('numberValue',function(){
$scope.numberVal=parseInt($scope.numberValue).toUpperCase();

});
```

**Also what if I need to separate them with example A => "A" Ab => "A","B" like 
this**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs force uppercase in textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388562/angularjs-force-uppercase-in-textbox)

Comment: no!!! the answer of it does not shows the change, instead blindly accepts the character as upper case I want it to be explicitly visible

Comment: Ok. Check my answer below and let me know if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: Is this just for presentation needs or do you want it also stored in the model upper-cased?

Comment: store the upper cased model in the same ng-model value. Also what if I need to separate them with example A => "A" Ab => "A","B" like this

Comment: @Aravind If you want to do such string manipulations , it's better to write that logic in a directive and use it as a component for any input box that needs this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a visible change, you can do like this : [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/suzo/kbwMY/43/)

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message" ng-change="toUpperCase()"/>
</div>
```

**Controller :**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.toUpperCase = function (){
    $timeout(function (){
      $scope.message = $scope.message.toUpperCase();
    }, 100)
  }
});
```

Comment: Increase the time in the `$timeout` function to see more visible change according to your requirement. Use the fiddle to decide that.