# How to autocapitalize an input field in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an input box.

I need to  autocapitalize  this box.

Is there any properties avaliable for this or do I need to code on controller

i also need that this effect is applyed in angular model

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242592/how-to-autocapitalize-an-input-field

Comment: i need all the input autocapitalize

Comment: First character only or all characters?

Comment: I hope you could make that logic from given code

Comment: this way http://jsfiddle.net/ruqy34fc/  Or this way http://jsfiddle.net/ruqy34fc/1/ ?

Comment: css text transforms works too, but it does not change the underlying value of the model

Comment: all characters need to  autocapitalize

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have a directive for this :)
The original code (written in TypeScript) is on GitHub https://github.com/ST-Software/STAngular/blob/master/src/directives/SgUpperCase.ts

//Fixed bug with cursor jumping at the end

```
someModule.directive("sgUpperCase", [function () {
    function getCaretPosition(inputField) {
        // Initialize
        var position = 0;
        // IE Support
        if (document.selection) {
            inputField.focus();
            // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
            var emptySelection = document.selection.createRange();
            // Move selection start to 0 position
            emptySelection.moveStart('character', -inputField.value.length);
            // The caret position is selection length
            position = emptySelection.text.length;
        }
        else if (inputField.selectionStart || inputField.selectionStart == 0) {
            position = inputField.selectionStart;
        }
        return position;
    }
    function setCaretPosition(inputElement, position) {
        if (inputElement.createTextRange) {
            var range = inputElement.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', position);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if (inputElement.selectionStart) {
                inputElement.focus();
                inputElement.setSelectionRange(position, position);
            }
            else {
                inputElement.focus();
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        require: "^ngModel",
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var toUpperCase = function (inputValue) {
                if (!inputValue)
                    return inputValue;
                var modified = inputValue.toUpperCase();
                if (modified !== inputValue) {
                    var position = getCaretPosition(elm[0]);
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(modified);
                    ctrl.$render();
                    setCaretPosition(elm[0], position);
                }
                return modified;
            };
            ctrl.$parsers.push(toUpperCase);
            toUpperCase(scope[attrs.ngModel]); //Transform initial value
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This also makes the cursor jump to the end if you type in the middle of the field.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Thanks for pointing that out, you are right. I will fix that

Answer (score 2):

You could use angular filter `uppercase` on change of that field using `ng-change`, If you want to make it capital on load then you should to same thing in `ng-init` too

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sample" ng-change="sample=(sample|uppercase)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `controller`.
`$watch` will listen for any changes made on `bic` and will update the value.

```
$scope.$watch('bic', function () {
    if ($scope.bic) {
        $scope.bic = $scope.bic.toUpperCase();
    }
});
```

Comment: This makes the cursor jump to the end every time you type something which is very annoying if you're making corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with CSS.

```css
input{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This text is auto capitalized" />
```

Comment: in my code it captlize first word only

Comment: @Ervikas, what browser are you on?

Comment: the CSS transform does transform the value of the field, so a normal form submit would contain the capitalized values. However, David Votrubec mentioned in another comment it does not change the underlying value of the model in angular

Comment: Whilst this may work, transforming the input value via CSS would not be reflected in the angular `model`. For the uppercasing to be permanent it must be applied by Angular.

Comment: yes you  are right @EdB . it does not effect on model in need to send also data in uppercase  to controller

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Jquery/Javascript for this one. Try this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="abc"   id="myid" class="span6" value="" name="">
```

In CSS

```
input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ruqy34fc/4/)**

Comment: I kind of like this, it's very unobtrusive, although you'll need to apply the transform in JS too afterwards if you want to have your string actually be uppercase. (But what does jQuery have to do with anything?)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen:- Agree, I said about jquery since the question was tagged with it ;)

Comment: Oh, all right. I wish people would stop tagging everything as jQuery because with Angular you rarely need it...

Answer (score 0):

Add class into input tag.
.capitalize {
    text-transform: uppercase"
}

```
i.e <input type="text" ng-model="bic" class="capitalize" id="txtbic" maxlength="11" class="span6" value="" name="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this  its working.. it also updates model...

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" uppercased/> {{name}}        
</div>

angular.module('components', [])
   .directive('uppercased', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',        
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(input) {
                return input ? input.toUpperCase() : "";
            });
            element.css("text-transform","uppercase");
        }
    };
});

angular.module('HelloApp', ['components'])
```

Working model [here](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/23/)