# Angular JS case-insensitive binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select menu that displays data from a json file, countries of the world by name.

I have a text field next to it which is bound to it and displays the iso 3166 alpha_2 data (e.g. CH for Switzerland).

Also, the user can enter the 2-character code and the correct name in the menu shows up.

[image]

My issue is that the user needs to type the alpha_2 value in *uppercase* to match.  Using my example above, typing "CH" works but "ch" shows no matches in the menu.

Is there a way to get around this?

```
  <td>
     <input type="text" size="4" ng-model="country_import.alpha_2">
  </td>
  <td>
     <select ng-model="country_import" ng-options="s.name for s in iso3166 track by s.alpha_2" class="form-control input-xs country-menu"></select>
  </td>
```

Comment: you can autocapitalize it. refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242592/how-to-autocapitalize-an-input-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.toUpperCase()` on the `track by` variable

`<select ng-model="country_import" ng-options="s.name for s in iso3166 track by s.alpha_2.toUpperCase()" class="form-control input-xs country-menu"></select>`

Here is plunker for similar case:
https://plnkr.co/edit/pESocfNey55uZb85RgDE?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would setup a watch on that, and turn everything a user types into Upper Case.

```
  $scope.$watch('country_import.alpha_2', function() {
        $scope.country_import.alpha_2 = $scope.country_import.alpha_2.toUpperCase();
  });
```