# The typeScript controllers

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to enforce capital letters on a form field, in Angular TypeScript?

For example, I have a request for a field "Name" that accepts capital letters only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autocapitalize the first character in an input field in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242592/how-to-autocapitalize-the-first-character-in-an-input-field-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can make uppercase using [`text-transform: uppercase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) :

```html
<input style="text-transform: uppercase" type="text" />
```

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) :

> The text-transform CSS property specifies how to capitalize an
>   element's text. It can be used to make text appear in all-uppercase or
>   all-lowercase, or with each word capitalized. It also can help improve
>   legibility for ruby.