# Text-transform on a Select box option

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I need a Select tag to have the style text-transform: uppercase and the options to be regular case.

This does not seem possible in chrome 69.

Comment: I think this thread might be usefull
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388301/does-text-transform-capitalize-work-for-option-elements-and-if-so-in-which-b/9696637

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to capitalize the text inside the selected `option` element.

```js
// get the select element

let select = document.querySelector("select");

// create a store for each options text values
let store = [];

for (let option of select ) {
  store.push(option.text);
}

// resets the last selected option's text back to it's default value 
function reset() {
  Array.prototype.map.call(select, option => {
    
    for(let text of store) {
      if(text.toUpperCase() == option.text) option.text = text;
    }
    
  });
}

// add the handler function for each time the select option is changed
select.addEventListener("change",  function (e) {
  if(this.selectedIndex == -1 ) return;
  
  reset();
  
  for( let selected of this.selectedOptions ) {
    selected.text =  selected.text.toUpperCase();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>Some text</option>
  <option>Some text</option>
  <option>Some text</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution of the select to be uppercase and the option to be regular case.

Comment: Just to be clear when you say "_select to be uppercase and the option to be regular case_" do you mean that you want the 1st option of the select element to be rendered uppercase and the other options to be rendered as you have written them in your markup?

Comment: The selected option that shows when the dropdown is closed is Uppercase. And the options when the dropdown is open have no forced casing.

Comment: @JP Since the OS is in control of how certain form elements are rendered I don't think you can change the styling with CSS. You can, however, use javascript to make the text uppercase. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what im looking for. Looking for a solution that any selected option becomes uppercase when being shown as the selected option and remains lowercase in the dropdown.

Comment: @JP I've updated my solution to this problem, please find the documentation in the comments. The solution should also work for select elements that allow for multiple options to be selected at once

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Chrome 69

```css
option {
  text-transform: none;
}

select {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>tHREe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have run the code snippet and all of the options are uppercase.

Comment: *I need a Select tag to have the style text-transform: uppercase* I guess you need something else than

Comment: [Screenshot of dropdown not not transforming](https://imagebin.ca/v/4JHMtF8O0aiJ)